# Pushforward of Coherent Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ a finite (especially affine) morphism between schemes and $F$ a ***coherent*** sheaf on $X$.

My question is how to verify that the pushforward $f_*F$ is also coherent?

Futhermore: Does this statement also holds for higher derived images $R^k f_*F$? Additionally can the assumption that $f$ is finite replaced by a weaker one (for example separated, proper or so on...)?

My ideas: Problem is finite and $f$ is affine, so wlog the problem translates to commutate algebra in following way:

$f: R \to A$ ring map and $M$ is $A$-module (this reflects the fact that $f_*F$ is quasi coherent).

Then $f_*M= M \vert _R$ is exactly the restriction of $M$ to $R$.

Does $f_*$ respect direct sums? (why?)

My hope would be to map a surjective map $A^r \to M$ (is given by coherence of $F = \overline{M}$) via $f_*$ to

$f_*A^r \to f_*M= M \vert _R$

So the problem depends on right exactness of $f_*$ and compatibility with sums. Could anybody help me to cope with these two obstructions?

Additionally, what would be the strategy for higher images $R^k f_*F$? These arise from presheaves $U \to H^k(U, f_*F)$? Since $f$ affine it seems that we also could work locally...

Comment: I think proper should be enough for (higher) direct images. As you said we can work locally, but the proof is not trivial, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O3
Edit : also compatibility with direct sum is kind of obvious right ?
Edit 2 : $f_*$ is NOT right exact in general else there will be no cohomology !!

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: yes, thank you for the reference. Concerning the compatibility with direct sums: how generally is the statement that $f_∗$ preserves direct sums? here I'm not sure. We know that $f_∗$ is right adjoint to $f^∗$; so the pushforward preserves limits but in general (for infinite index) direct sums and products differ. Or do you mean in your last comment that this does only hold in the case $f$ finite? In this case it is "obvious" in the sense that just a retriction of a free $A$-module $M$ to $R$ stays ($R$-)free. Or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: In term of sheaves, $f_*F(U) = F(f^{-1}(U))$ and hence it's clear that $(f_*(F \oplus G))(U) = (F \oplus G)(f^{-1}(U)) = f_*F(U) \oplus f_*G(U)$

Comment: ...of course,sorry for dumb question. I had the whole time ***local*** freeness/ decomposition in direct sum in mind

Comment: so for $f$ finite the story is much simpler: We have surjections $A^r \to M$ (by coherence) and $R^k \to A$ (by finiteness) so the composition of these two gives that $M \vert _R$ is coherent (=locally quotient of $R^{kr}$)